# Is Xpath rule deprecated in Sonar 4.5.1

Tags: java, xpath, sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5

I have customized the xpath rule template but seems its not working. The xpath query successfully got validated in SSLR java toolkit but the same is not working in Sonar when being set as a new xpath rule. Could you please confirm soon if Xpath rule deprecated in Sonar 4.5.1  or what is right way then? We recently upgraded from SonarQube 4.0 to 4.5.1 and this rule is newly added in 4.5.1 version.

Comment: What's your version of the Java plugin?

Comment: sonar-java-plugin-2.9.1 @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam

Answer (score 2):

XPath rules are neither provided nor deprecated by the platform itself, so platform version is largely irrelevant here (the Java plugin is distributed with the platform but you can substitute a different version).

That said, it was version 2.5 of the Java plugin, released in Oct. 2014, that dropped support for XPath rules. The plugins for [several other languages](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Adding+Custom+Rules+using+XPath+Expressions) still offer support for XPath rules, but because any new version of a plugin may change the "shape" of the syntax tree, XPath rules can abruptly stop working and should be re-tested after each relevant plugin upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Xpath Rule is deprecated in this version, the oldest rule developped with xpath rule will be removed also with this versio.

But You can Create a new plugin Custom java rule to define your specific rule.

Cdt,
Youssef